# e-mail validation loop in java not working

Tags: java

It seems that this question has been asked million times already, yet I cannot find a solution to my problem. I have defined the scanner, called all the functions beforehand AND this is the piece of code I am trying to work with now.

Loop needs to validate the email provided, if it is not in the format name@name.com then reject it and repeat - this works fine - My problem is that whenever I provide the correct email format it seems as if the loop never stops, and never displays correct email notification nether does it save the input to string localEmailAddress.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
    static Scanner userInputString = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your email address (ex. myname@email.com): ");
    String emailregrex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z0-9]+$";
        do {
            while (!userInputString.next().matches(emailregrex)) {
                System.out.println("Please provide correct email!");
            }
          
        } while (userInputString.next().matches(emailregrex));
        System.out.printf("Correct email!"); 

      String localEmailAdress = userInputString.next();
```

Comment: Make sure you are closing your scanner resource also .

Comment: On a successful email read you are just trying to read another in the while part of the do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you provided, you are essentially saying "do a loop until it matches while it matches". It sounds like you'd rather have "do this loop until it matches". The solution would basically just to move the inner loop outside, and store the value so you don't keep requesting it.

```java
static Scanner userInputString = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your email address (ex. myname@email.com): ");
String emailregrex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z0-9]+$";
String localEmailAddress = userInputString.next();

while (!localEmailAddress.matches(emailregrex) {
    System.out.println("Please provide correct email!");
    localEmailAddress = userInputString.next();
}

System.out.printf("Correct email!");
```

Comment: Happy to help @MartinWalczyński! If it worked for you, do you mind marking it as correct?